# ResourceDictionary administration

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

The main WPF project has resources defined in `App.xaml`.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary                     
                Source="pack://application:,,,/Views;component/Themes/Standard.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Here `Views` is another project which contains all kinds of UserControls.
This works all right, except that in the UserControls xaml the styles of Standard.xaml are not recognized because in this project App.xaml is not loaded.

So, compile time warnings like `Resource cannot be resolved` are shown.
It can be fixed by adding

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary            
                Source="pack://application:,,,/Views;component/Themes/Standard.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

to all `UserControl` files, but I would like to add this only one time somewhere in this project that doesn't contain `App.xaml`.

I can also ignore the warnings of course.
Inheritance for `UserControl` is when I understand correctly only possibe in a `.cs` file, not with a `.xaml` file.

Any other suggestions?